# Fetch values of key-value in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display the values of all key-value pairs in an array of objects. I've tried several methods, for example http://jsfiddle.net/4Mrkp/, but I can't seem to get it to work on my data.

The data, I want to display the car makes only:

```
{
"response":{
        "status":"200",
        "messages":{},
        "milliseconds":"2"
        },
"input":{
        "provinceid":{},
        "supplierid":"12345678",
        "statusid":{        }
        },
"output":{
        "count":"7",
        "list":{
            "make":[
                {"name":"Alfa Romeo"},
                {"name":"Audi"},
                {"name":"BMW"},
                {"name":"Chevrolet"},
                {"name":"Chrysler"},
                {"name":"Citroen"},
                {"name":"Dacia"}
            ]
        }}
}
```

My code so far, this displays the word `make`:

```
function display_makes(obj)
{

    document.getElementById("temp-id").innerHTML = 
    Object.keys(obj.output.list.make).forEach(function(key){
        document.write(key);});
}
```

So next step is to fetch the values of each element of `make`, but how? Any thoughts?

Comment: For each `value` in `obj.output.list.make` you'll want `value.name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Object.keys` on `obj.output.list.make` because it's an array, use:

```
obj.output.list.make.forEach(function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use underscoreJS for manipulating the JSON.

```
var make = _.map(json_object.output.list.make,function(make) {
    document.write(make.name);
    return make;
})
```

This make variable will contain values in key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier than you think. Just iterate over the array and forget about the rest:

```
object.output.list.make.forEach(function(item){
    document.write(item);
});
```

You are working with the array therefore you do not need at all the `Object.keys()`

Comment: Thanks for reply! This worked when changing document.write(item); into document.write(item.name);